# how to change radgrid's GridButtonColumn's text in radgrid's ItemCommand event?

Tags: gridview, radgrid

I have a radgrid with GridButtonColumn as one of the column.I need to change that column's text displayed in the grid during ItemCommand event.
for eg.
if text is 'yes' after ItemCommand event, it should be changed to 'no'.
How we can implement this?

Answer (score 3):

See: [How to change GridButtonColumn image/text at runtime](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/how-to-change-gridbuttoncolumn-image-text-change-at-runtime.aspx)

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem) 
    { 
        GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
        LinkButton lbutton = item["ButtonUniqueName"].Controls[0] as LinkButton;
        if (lbutton.Text == "yes") 
        { 
           lbutton.Text = "no";
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This worked wonders for me as I was attempting to get at the row information via the item command event.